# How to parse xml data when end element is having forward and backward slash

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am getting response from server like a

```
 <DataSet>\u000d\u000a
     <Table>\u000d\u000a
        <USER_NAME>Ganesh<\/USER_NAME>\u000d\u000a  
     <\/Table>\u000d\u000a
 <\/DataSet>"
```

and if am trying to parse it by using NSXmal Parser delegate methods,it's giving error like a

> localizedDescription The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSXMLParserErrorDomain error 4.)

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Replace \/ with / before parsing.

Comment: that is not xml. to use a parser on it you would have to fix it with a string replace or better yet fix the source

Comment: what about \u000d\u000a ? and is string replacing good way?

Comment: `<USER_NAME>Ganesh<\/USER_NAME>\u000d\u000a` <-- Is it correct xml ?

Comment: alternative is you can find the `NSString` what you want.

Comment: Personally I think you should fix the server instead of client workarounds because this is not XML.

Comment: [NSString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES] , use it to convert your unicode data to ascii value.

Comment: That's some really crappy data from the server.

Comment: For the time being I wrote like this and it's working fine.  NSString *str=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        str =[[[str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\/" withString:@"/"] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\u000d\\u000a" withString:@""] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@""]; But i don't know wether it's correct solution or not.

Answer (score 0):

First In the case of working will `XML` you need to follow the rules for Creating. As you `XML` is not correct number of issue with `Tag` name etc is there.

And if there some issue then another like if you have All `XML` in String then you can find the `NSString` between two `Strings` with the method. Or in other Words you can find the `tag` value using this.

```
-(NSString*)stringBetweenString:(NSString*)start andString:(NSString)end {
    NSRange startRange = [self rangeOfString:start];
    if (startRange.location != NSNotFound) {
        NSRange targetRange;
        targetRange.location = startRange.location + startRange.length;
        targetRange.length = [self length] - targetRange.location;   
        NSRange endRange = [self rangeOfString:end options:0 range:targetRange];
        if (endRange.location != NSNotFound) {
           targetRange.length = endRange.location - targetRange.location;
           return [self substringWithRange:targetRange];
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your xml string with this

```
   NSString *html=xmlString;

   html = [html stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:[ NSString stringWithFormat:@"<\\"] withString:@"<"];
```

Answer (score 0):

That's mean that response from server has wrong encoding.